# Is it possible to load a view when we click a coverflow image? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is it possible to load a view when we click a coverflow image?

Please suggest how this can be done.

Comment: In iPhone, we have coverflow to see ipod albums. Similarly, can we have coverflow to browse images and on selecting one image, it opens a view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go ;)

http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m

Please vote this post up if it helps :D

Comment: its great that there is coverflow ..but clicking on the image aint navigating to next view ...any idea

Answer (score 0):

CoverFlow is not a standard iOS component. It doesn't have a public API. You'll need to either create your own or use a library someone else created.

In answer to your question, it is possible to load a view when you click an image. The iPod app probably creates a view, then uses an animation to present it onscreen.

Comment: There are few API's available for CoverFlow which I can get. But my problem is how to load the view when I click an image on it.

Comment: The question you're asking ("How do I load a view?") is a very open question. You'll have to create a view (`alloc`, `init`) then decide how you want it to appear, then tell it to appear that way. I'd really suggest reading the iOS View Programming guide first, then asking a specific question. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html